# Multiple rows calculation SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table :

```
UNIQUE KEY ID      Clicks    INSERTDATE
 1         100001   10     2011-05-14 00:00:00.000
 2         100001   20     2011-05-13 00:00:00.000
 3         100001   30     2011-05-18 00:00:00.000
 4         100002   10     2011-05-20 00:00:00.000
 5         100002   15     2011-05-24 00:00:00.000
 6         100002   10     2011-05-05 00:00:00.000
```

I have a threshold value for clicks, lets say 20.

I need to write a T-SQL which should remove the clicks that do not meet the threshold of the accumulative Sum of clicks for each ID.

So for the above example ID "100001" has an accumulative clicks of 60 (10+20+30) but since the threshold is 20, the last record i.e. with the click value of 30 should get removed from the result.
However, the second record should still be included even though the sum at that point is > my threshold (10 + 20).

EDIT :

Another major rule that needs to be applied is that the INSERTDATE has to be ordered before performing any calculations

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you'd like to filter on the RunningTotal for a given Id, like so:

```
select c1.*
from ClickTable c1
outer apply (
  select sum(Clicks) as RunningTotal
  from ClickTable 
  where pk < c1.pk
    and id = c1.id
) c2
where isnull(RunningTotal, 0) <= 20
```

this implies that you have a unique key field in the table, called `PK`.

#### Running sample: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98173/11

### Update

To order by Clicks instead of the primary key, just change the line

```
where pk < c1.pk
```

to

```
where Clicks < c1.Clicks
```

#### Running sample: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31750/2

Comment: +1 If OP doesn't have an incrementing PK then could apply an intermediate ranking with ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: Nice ! can we somehow apply ORDER BY in the sub query on Clicks, otherwise lets say if 20 is the first one it will just ignore the rest?

Comment: @nonnb Right! I didn't think of that.

Comment: @MurtazaMandvi Currently the subselect sums up all the records that have a lower PK value than the current one, so I would say that no `ORDER BY` clause is needed; the Running Total is computed in the order given by PK

Comment: @MurtazaMandvi if 20 were first it would not ignore the rest, because I used `<=` for comparison. If you use `<`, then yes, it would.

Comment: probably did not explain my comment before better,having an order by is really important otherwise the calculations will go off, example : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31750/1/0 see how I put 21, 10 and 15 for the first set of ID (10001), however when you run it it will just take 21 and figure its reached the max i.e. it's > 20.What I need is for this data it should have returned me 5,10,and 20 since 5+10 is still lower than 20, and thus the requirement to Sort the clicks- get it?

Comment: OK, now I understand that this is a requirement. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Nope, now if you check the second record set (100002) which has 10,15 and 10, the output should have stopped at 10+15=25, however it did output 10+15+10

Comment: yes, because it now orders items by clicks. So, in fact it takes 10+10+15.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, I edited my question to add one more (final) requirement :) ....the INSERT Date, I tried ordering by the Insert Date (Desc) but that did not work? So now the same logic runs as you have provided but the inner query has to first Order by INSERTDATE first before doing the threshold calc.

Comment: I am almost at the edge of receiving the results correctly, only if you help me out with the final Edit that I posted ! Thanks !

Comment: @MurtazaMandvi doesn't it work if you just replace the `where ...` line to `where INSERTDATE < c1.INSERTDATE` ?

Comment: @MurtazaMandvi That would compute for each row the sum of Clicks for all the earlier records that have the same ID. I think that should solve it.

Comment: That does not work,because it still does not sort the date desc i.e. brng the latest date first.http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68f8b/1/0 if you see here for recordset 100001 was supposed to be sorted by having datekey 13 as the first record however it just took 11 as the first one and performed the threshold. (ive used int in the datekey example just so its easier to insert integers than dates)

Comment: I inverted the date condition (`datekey > c1.datekey` instead of `datekey < c1.datekey`). The result is now ordered by date desc: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68f8b/2 . Is this OK?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I read the question correctly. Seems too simple:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Clicks) AS Clicks 
FROM t1
WHERE Clicks <= 20                 -- <== this is your threshold
GROUP BY ID
```

Would give you

```
ID     Clicks
100001 30
100002 35
```

Comment: I think he wants <= 20, not > 20

Comment: @Greg caught that as well and fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the actual requirement, if you check above what @w0lf did is pretty close to what is required.